# How to make a sum of total for each id and grand total

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Table 1

```
id name
001 raja
002 vijay
003 suresh
```

Table 2

```
id value
001 100
001 200
001 150
002 200
003 150
003 200
```

and i want the out put like this

```
id name value
001 raja 450
002 vijay 200
003 suresh 350
................
           1000 (sum of value)
```

using crystal report

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you having troubles with?

Comment: Why is this tagged as Sql ?

Comment: my query is in sql, may be my joins wrong thats why i have taged Sql

Comment: you need to add atleast what have you tried and where are you struck?

Answer (score 0):

```
       Select  table2.id,table1.name, 
        sum(table2.value) from table2,table1 
       where table2.id= (table1.id)
        group by table2.id 
       union 
        select '----','-----',sum(value) from table2
      ;
```

> This will give you the sum of values of each specific group id with name